# Printing Range of Excel cells using interop [c#]

Tags: c#, printing, interop

I'm trying to print range of excel file, however when I write this lines `Range("A:1","D10")` is underlined with statement that "Non-invocable member of _Worksheet.Range[object, oject] cannot be used like a method".

How do i change this and make it work?

(I'm using COM Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel)

```
xlWorkSheet.Range("A1:D10").PrintOutEx(misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue,
        misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[You use the wrong brackets](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/microsoft.office.tools.excel.worksheet.range.aspx) **(** [is for VB](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/microsoft.office.tools.excel.worksheet.range.aspx)

```
xlWorkSheet.Range["A1:D10"].PrintOutEx(misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue,
        misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue);
```